# Find the number of times a number is repeated in an array in less than O(n^2)

Tags: java, algorithm, complexity-theory

Sample code that I have written.But this is n^2

```
int a[]={1,4,1,5,2,2,4,3,4,1};
int b[][]=new int[5][2];
int i,j,k=0,count=1;
boolean temp=false;
for(i=0;i<a.length;i++)
{
    for(j=0;j<5;j++)
    {
        if(a[i]==b[j][0])
        {   temp=true;
            b[j][1]++;
            break;
        }
    }

    if(temp==false)
    {
        b[k][0]=a[i];
        b[k][1]=1;
        k++;    
    }
    temp=false;
}
for(i=0;i<5;i++)
{
    for(j=0;j<1;j++)
    {
    System.out.println(b[i][j]+" is repeated "+b[i][j+1]+" times");
    }
}
```

Comment: I am running tha second loop 5 times ..its for the array which I have used as it contains less than 5 diff digits.Max value can be the length of the array..if it contains all unique element..Any suggestion on reducing time complexity

Comment: unless you have serious constraints on memory I'd go with an occurrence counter like @DTing and @ThiefMaster proposed.

Answer (score 7):

Here's a solution in pseudocode:

```
Map<Int, Int> histogram;
for(number in array) {
    histogram[number]++;
}
```

Now `histogram[somenumber]` contains the number of times the number is in the array - in `O(n)` assuming the `Map` looks up items in `O(1)`

Comment: +1: The method `TIntIntHashMap.adjustOrPutValue(number,1,1)` springs to mind. ;)

Answer (score 5):

Option 1: sacrifice memory for speed.

- Use a data structure like a `HashMap` to record frequencies of each number.
- Iterate through in O(n) time to build the frequency counts, then either iterate through whole HashMap or extract one value.

Option 2: sort

- Sort, then either iterate through the whole sorted structure or O(log n) to seek to a particular value.

  - Quicksort has average n log n, O(n^2) worst case, is in-place for memory.
  - Mergesort or heapsort are O(n log n) but takes up extra memory during sort

Comment: quicksort has worst case O(n^2). You must use mergesort, heapsort or another sort with complexity less than O(n^2).

Comment: @Ishtar: quicksort is perfectly fine. If implemented correctly, the odds of it performing badly are less than the probability of the host computer being hit by a meteorite.

Comment: @abeln - "Find the number of times a number is repeated in an array **in less than O(n^2)**". Meteorites or no meteorites, it is technically not correct.

Comment: Just change to "O(n log n) for a quick sort" to appease the nitpickers :)

Comment: @Ishtar: you're right. I didn't realize it was homework, so the actual upper bound might matter. I was thinking more about the "practical" side.

Comment: Edited to take quicksort worst case into account.  Thanks all!

Comment: Heapsort does not require more space. In fact, heapsort requires `O(1)` extra space whereas quicksort requires `O(logn)` extra space.

Answer (score 3):

Pseudocode:

```
counts = dictionary default to 0

for each element in list:
    counts[element]+=1
```

O(n)

Comment: +0: This only works if you know the range of `int` values in advance. e.g. if you assume `[Integer.MIN_VALUE..Integer.MAX_VALUE]` it won't work so well.

Comment: @Hippo, Because that is 4 billion values and you cannot create an array. If you could it would use between 16. If you were to use a Map style dictionary like TIntIntHashMap or Map<Integer, Integer> you would not get O(n) worst case.

Answer (score 2):

You should use eg. merge sort to sort your array and then use a simple for-loop to go through the whole array to count the repeats.

Merge sort has n*log(n) and a for-loop to find the repeats is also quick.

Answer (score 1):

A fast sorting algorithm should be much faster than O(n^2), and that followed by a group, which is O(n) should still be faster than O(n^2).

Therefore, in pseudocode:

```
    group (sort [1,2,3,3,2,1])   =>   [(1,2), (2,2), (3,2)]
```

Answer (score 1):

You can achive in O(n) time by creating another datastructure like map.
Ex:
    int a[]={1,4,1,5,2,2,4,3,4,1};

```
Map<Integer, Integer> map = new HashMap<Integer, Integer>();

for(int i = 0; i < a.length ; i++)
{
    if(map.containsKey(a[i]))
    {
        map.put(a[i], map.get(a[i])+1);
    }
    else
    {
        map.put(a[i], 1);
    }
}

System.out.print(map);
```

Result: {1=3, 2=2, 3=1, 4=3, 5=1}

Answer (score 0):

Why do you use a 2-dim array? If your numbers are known to be in range 1..5, use the index for the number:

```
    int a[] = {1,4,1,5,2,2,4,3,4,1};
    int b[] = new int[5];

    for (int n : a)
        ++b[n-1];

    for (int j=0; j < 5; ++j)
        System.out.println (j + " is repeated " + b [j-1] + " times");
```

- Don't declare Variables premature, and don't reuse them. You will forget to delete unused variables (count), and get hard to analyze code.
- Use the improved for : loop.
- Declare counters in the head - there is a reason why this is allowed: for (int i = ...) and why i isn't visible outside the block. It's not expensive. No, it isn't. Look at the bytecode.

Answer (score 0):

If you can alter the existing array you can do this. Its O(n log(n)) and doesn't create an new objects. (If you cannot alter the original you can clone it.) Its much more efficient than maintaining a Map. ;)

```
int a[] = {1, 4, 1, 5, 2, 2, 4, 3, 4, 1};

Arrays.sort(a);
int last = a[0];
int count = -1; 
for (int i : a) {
    if (i == last) {
        count++;
        continue;
    }
    System.out.println("Number " + last + " found " + count + " times.");
    count = 1;
    last = i;
}
System.out.println("Number " + last + " found " + count + " times.");
```

prints

```
Number 1 found 3 times.
Number 2 found 2 times.
Number 3 found 1 times.
Number 4 found 3 times.
Number 5 found 1 times.
```

Answer (score 0):

Reducing O(n^2) to O(n*log n) is simple in this case:

1. Sort the numbers using heapsort/quicksort ... O(n*log n)
2. Traverse the array once and count unique elements and get their counts ... O(n)

Keeping a height balanced tree with numbers as keys along with the occurrence count is another idea which will give O(n*log n). I don't see an O(n) solution without using a hash-table like data structure which is readily available in most languages.

Comment: quicksort has worst case O(n^2).

Comment: That's why I suggested "heapsort/quicksort".

BTW, quicksort can be done done in O(n*log n) if you use the median finding algorithm in O(n) each step. of partitioning. However, this is mostly of academic interests as the median finding algorithm in O(n) has very high value of the constants.